# Usb-c Hubs with power delivery support

Tags: usb-c, hub

I was considering to buy a usb-c hub for my new laptop Asus TUF fx507 model and the thing is that it does not support usb-c power delivery BUT I actually don't need it. I just need to know does that power delivery port on the hub itself provides its power from the outer source to its internal ports. I mean does the hub provide power to its usb ports and not just for the laptop itself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your laptop doesn’t support power delivery over USB Type-C why do you want a USB Hub that supports it. The hub would have to be externally powered to accomplish that requirement

Comment: I mean if i would externally power my hub with a wall charge than would this hub deliver the power from wall charge to other devices that are connected to the hub via usb ? As you said i don't need to power my laptop via power delivery cause it doesn't support it

Comment: Yes, there are powered USB hubs. When you look for Power Delivery USB hubs though you're mostly going to find hubs that allow you to power the host laptop.

Answer (score -2):

THey usb-c is only output .. So there is no input 5V is reserved to power peripherals you connect to usb-c

Edit:  some idiot gave me downvote.. But he is so stuid that I meant no input in those lapotps which has no power delivery so power in is terminated to ''dead end'' track !
Why lillt eboys here are so naive here?? ‍♂️

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).